# how to draw a white dot in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, androidx, android-tablayout

I was trying to use white dot as tab icon in tablayout in android studio.

I have use a example from online to define the dot:

ic_tab_default.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:innerRadius="0dp"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thickness="24dp"
    android:useLevel="false">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>

</shape>
```

however, it became a square after I add it, how can I make it to a dot?

Answer (score 1):

**tab_default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="oval"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this would work

```xml
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="10dp"
    android:height="10dp"
    android:tint="#ffffff"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#ffffff"
        android:pathData="M12,2C6.48,2 2,6.48 2,12s4.48,10 10,10 10,-4.48 10,-10S17.52,2 12,2zM10,9z" />
</vector>
```